# LazyInitializationException using HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm trying to use HibernateDaoSupport but I'm getting stuck with a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException problem.

This is an example of what I want to do;

```
public class MyDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public Set<Long> getCoreItemIdsForCustomerIds(Set<Long> customerIds) {
        Set<Long> itemIds = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (Long customerId : customerIds) {
            Customer customer = getCustomerWithId(customerId);
            itemIds.addAll(getItemIdsFromItems(customer.getCoreItems()));
        }
        return itemIds;
    }

    private Customer getCustomerWithId(Long customerId) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().get(Customer.class, customerId);
    }

    private Set<Long> getItemIdsFromItems(Set<Item> items) {
        Set<Long> itemIds = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (Item item : items) {
            itemIds.add(item.getId());
        }
        return itemIds;
    }
}
```

A Customer has a collection of Items. The entity is Fetched lazily, so I guess the problem is after **getCustomerWithId** completes the session is closed, and 'customer' is now detached. So when **customer.getCoreItems()** is invoked the exception is thrown.

Does any one know how I can use HibernateDaoSupport and keep the session open until **getCoreItemIdsForCustomerIds** returns?

Or do I need to start and close the transaction manually myself to do this?

Hope that has made sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OpenSessionInView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) filter. The session will be open for the duration of the request-response render phase.

Comment: Yeah I read about when I was Googling earlier. It's not really the right solution as in my views I will not be trying to access properties that are loaded lazily.

Comment: @C0deAttack well you must be or else you wouldn't be getting the Lazy Exception. Or is that code being execute in some Cron Task or Timer or something?

Comment: @C0deAttack Yeah i read that but my ? is what is going on that happens after the response has been rendered and why can't you use the OpenSessionInView pattern?